# Regex matching word then looking backwards until another word, then grabbing everything in between

Tags: python, regex

Here is a sample of text:

> MM is a staple for an everyday casual look. Crafted from red epi
>   leather, this structured yet feminine tote features dual flat leather
>   handles, engraved LV studs, subtle logo, protective base studs and
>   silver-tone hardware accents. Its top zipper closure opens to a
>   matching red fabric-lined interior which slip and zip pockets housing
>   all daily essentials.

I want to grab the interior color, so I am searching for "interior" then, backwards from interior, looking for "a" with whitespace on either side. This is being used in Python.

Based on my research, the following should work but the lookbehind is not working.

```
(?<!\sa\s).+(?= interior)
```

This gets me:

"MM is a staple for an everyday casual look. Crafted from red epi leather, this structured yet feminine tote features dual flat leather handles, engraved LV studs, subtle logo, protective base studs and silver-tone hardware accents. Its top zipper closure opens to a matching red fabric-lined"

instead of what I want:
"matching red fabric-lined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search from the point of `a` forwards. `\ba\b ((?:[^\.](?!\ba\b))*?) interior` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXqJ3N/3))

In place of `[^\.]`. You can use `.`. I chose what I chose because I assume this match shouldn't ever extend across sentences but I can see where abbreviations might be a possibility in your text. The choice is yours. If the first setup suits your needs, the regex performs less searching before it moves on from a false match.

Part of the reason your regex doesn't do what you want is that the first thing it encounters `MM..` definitely does meet the condition of not being prefixed by `a`. Perhaps you intended a *positive lookbehind*, `(?<=\sa\s).+(?= interior)`, but that still *[captures too much](https://regex101.com/r/FXqJ3N/3)*. It would probably still need to feature checking syntax like most of my expression to get the narrow group you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
( a )((?:(?!\1|interior).)*) interior
```

`( a )` and `interior` are the sentinels that determine where the match can occur, and `(?:(?!\1|interior).)*` matches anything but the sentinels.  The desired text is captured in group 2.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/WsYPWV/1)